# 2's complement, bytes to int giving high values

Tags: binary, hex

I'm using a pic to read values from a sensor and I receive values outside the sensor range. I think it can be a conversion issue.
This is the code I'm using:

```
long readvalue=(long)((i2coctetlist[0] << 8) | (i2coctetlist[1]));
```

And here an example:

> the 2 bytes received: 01111111 11001101 and the result : 32717

Is there an error in my code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that all the types in Java are signed and the values are sign-extended when converting to wider type. This happens for both explicit cast (`(long)`) and automatic conversion due to operation (`x<<y` converts `x` at least to `int`, the same for `x|y` - operands are first converted to at least `int`).

Due to this `(0x00<<8)|(0xf0)` results into `0xfffffff0` because the second (actually both) operand is first converted into `0xfffffff0` and the `|` operation is performed.

The solution is to always mask with the byte `0xff` which converts to `int` and then applies the byte mask:

```
 int readValue = (byte0&0xff)|((byte1&0xff)<<8)|...
 // if needed, conversion to long should also mask 32 bits
 long longValue = readValue&0xffffffffL;
```

Comment: I tried with a mask but it gives the same value, and in fact it seems normal as 0111111111001101 is 32717 in decimal, the problem must be somewhere else...